# Using jQuery to update a web page. Why doesn't this code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a calculator for a simple physics equation. The data is collected using a web form, and then answer should be returned and updated onto the original web page. However no matter what I do or change I can't get the answer to display on the web page. Why isn't this working?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../../Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Calculator.js"></script>
<title>Physics calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>F=MA calculator</h1>

<div>
    <img src="fma.jpg">
</div>

<div>
    <form>
      Force: <input type="text" name="force" id='force'>
    </form>
    <form>
      Mass: <input type="text" name="mass" id='mass'>
    </form>
    <form>
      Acceleration: <input type="text" name="acc" id='acc'>
    </form>

    <div>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id='calculate'>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p id='answer'></p> 
    </div>


</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calculate').on('click', function() {
        var F = $('#force').val();
        var M = $('#mass').val();
        var A = $('#acc').val();

        if (F!=="number" && typeof M==="number" && typeof A==="number") {   
            var FMA = M*A;
            $('#answer').html("The force is " +FMA " Newtons.")
        }


        else if (typeof M!=="number" && typeof F==="number" && typeof A==="number") {
            var MFA = F/A;
            var $output2 = $('<p>The mass is ?? kg.</p>');
            $('#answer').html("The mass is " +MFA " kg.")
        }


        else if (typeof A!=="number" && typeof F==="number" && typeof M==="number") {
            var AFM = F/M;
            $('#answer').html("The acceleration is " +AFM " metres per second sqaured.");
        }


        else {
            $('#answer').html("A calculation error has occurred.");
        }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code. I prefer using the isNaN function to check if the value is actually a number. You were also missing a plus sign when concatenating the answer string.

$('#calculate').on('click', function() {

```
    var F = $('#force').val(),
        M = $('#mass').val(),
        A = $('#acc').val();

    if (isNaN(F) && !isNaN(M) && !isNaN(A)) {

        var FMA = M*A;
        $('#answer').html("The force is " + FMA + " Newtons.");

    } else if (isNaN(M) && !isNaN(F) && !isNaN(A)) {

        var MFA = F/A;
        var $output2 = $('<p>The mass is ?? kg.</p>');
        $('#answer').html("The mass is " + MFA + " kg.");

    } else if (isNaN(A) && !isNaN(F) && !isNaN(M)) {

        var AFM = F/M;
        $('#answer').html("The acceleration is " + AFM + " metres per second squared.");

    } else {

        $('#answer').html("A calculation error has occurred.");

    }
```

});

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9a1u23r/

Answer (score 1):

You had `typeof` and concatenation errors.
(If you're not interested in *Infinite* results) **[Try with:](http://jsbin.com/sakef/1/edit)**

```
$('#calculate').on('click', function() {

    var F = parseInt( $('#force').val(), 10);
    var M = parseInt( $('#mass').val(), 10);
    var A = parseInt( $('#acc').val(), 10);
    var msg = "A calculation error has occurred.";

           if (isNaN(F) && M && A) {
        msg = "The force is "+ (M*A) +" Newtons."; 
    } else if (isNaN(M) && F && A) {
        msg = "The mass is "+ (F/A) +" kg.";
    } else if (isNaN(A) && F && M) {
        msg = "The acceleration is "+ (F/M) +" metres per second sqaured.";
    }

    $('#answer').html(msg);
});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I hadn't spotted that snafu. The issue I'm having is that nothing appears in the '#answer' element.

Answer (score 0):

Not only concatenated with string. You need parse to INT, so the typeof number works. Also you can use the isNaN function:

```
  if (isNaN(F) && !isNaN(M) && !isNaN(A)) {
        var FMA = M*A;
        $('#answer').html("The force is " +FMA +" Newtons.")
    }

    else if (isNaN(M) && !isNaN(F) && !isNaN(A)) {
        var MFA = F/A;
        var $output2 = $('<p>The mass is ?? kg.</p>');
        $('#answer').html("The mass is " +MFA + " kg.")
    }

    else if (isNaN(A) && !isNaN(F) && !isNaN(M)) {
        var AFM = F/M;
        $('#answer').html("The acceleration is " +AFM + " metres per second sqaured.");
    }

    else {
        $('#answer').html("A calculation error has occurred.");
    }
```

You must check if any value is empty. I hope help you.

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/v95vwrm2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the JS Fiddle code, that works exactly as planned.

It doesn't seem to work when I change my own code the same way though. Is there some trick that JS Fiddle uses I need to include in my own code?

Comment: Solved by hosting jquery locally, rather to linking to a site hosting it.